# formatting text in footer (text under icons)

Tags: html, css

I need help formatting the footer for my website. I am new to CSS and I cannot figure out how to get the text for the Copyright to sit underneath of the icons. I tried tweaking by altering the height of the footer and the best I can get is the text to the left or right of the icons. Any help would be appreciated.

CSS Style Sheet:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.navBar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 61px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navBar a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

body.services a.services,
body.ourstory a.ourstory {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.p3 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
.p4 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 200px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

HTML Document:

```css
.content {
  padding: 10.4%;
}

.main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.copyright {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.navbarSocialMedia {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFooter {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.navbarSocialMedia a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.mediaLogo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

<title>Giving Back</title>

    <link href="simpleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="name.png">

    </head>

    <body class="services">

    <div class="header">

        <a href="simple.html">
            <img src="name.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"> </a>

        <div class="navBar">
            <a href="ourstory.html" class="ourstory">Our Story</a>
            <a href="services.html" class="services">Giving Back</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">

            <p class="p3"> content

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="newFooter">
        <div class="navbarSocialMedia">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="InstagramLogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="linkedin48.png " alt="linked in logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="emaillogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com " target="_blank">
                <img src="facebooklogo48.png " alt="facebook logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
        </div>

        <div class="try">
            <p class=" copyright ">Copyright &copy. </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Write your code in snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code change on `.copyright` and `.navbarSocialMedia` CSS. Mainly to change the position on `.copyright` and align the bottom of `.navbarSocialMedia`.

```css
.content {
  padding: 10.4%;
}

.main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.copyright {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  /* display: block;*/
  /* Add fixed position */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  /* margin-bottom: 100px; */
}

.navbarSocialMedia {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2.5em; /* Change to 2.5em for the copyright space */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFooter {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.navbarSocialMedia a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.mediaLogo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

  <title>Giving Back</title>

  <link href="simpleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="name.png">

</head>

<body class="services">

  <div class="header">

    <a href="simple.html">
      <img src="name.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"> </a>

    <div class="navBar">
      <a href="ourstory.html" class="ourstory">Our Story</a>
      <a href="services.html" class="services">Giving Back</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">

      <p class="p3"> content

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newFooter">

    <div class="navbarSocialMedia">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="InstagramLogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="linkedin48.png " alt="linked in logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
      <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="emaillogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com " target="_blank">
        <img src="facebooklogo48.png " alt="facebook logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="try">
      <p class=" copyright ">Copyright &copy. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the copyright div is not visible is because your `<div class="navbarSocialMedia">` has a position fixed, so it is displayed on top of the footer (that also has a fixed position).

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.
>   [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

I set `bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` footer's attributes so it's displayed on the bottom of the window and with full width.

Also I would suggest to remove the `margin-bottom: 100px` from the `<p class="copyright">` as it takes too much space from the window.

And last but not least, I noticed that for the `<div class="navbarSocialMedia">` you had set `text-align: center` (so I'm assuming you want the icons to be centered) but as it has the property `display: flex`. It's better to use `align-items: center` instead.

Hope this helps you out.

```css
.content {
  padding: 10.4%;
}

.main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.copyright {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  display: block;
}

.navbarSocialMedia {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.newFooter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbarSocialMedia a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.mediaLogo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

<title>Giving Back</title>

    <link href="simpleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="name.png">

    </head>

    <body class="services">

    <div class="header">

        <a href="simple.html">
            <img src="name.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"> </a>

        <div class="navBar">
            <a href="ourstory.html" class="ourstory">Our Story</a>
            <a href="services.html" class="services">Giving Back</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">

            <p class="p3"> content

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="newFooter">
        <div class="navbarSocialMedia">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="InstagramLogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="linkedin48.png " alt="linked in logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="emaillogo48.png " alt="email logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com " target="_blank">
                <img src="facebooklogo48.png " alt="facebook logo" class="mediaLogo"> </a>
        </div>

        <div class="try">
            <p class=" copyright ">Copyright &copy. </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

added red background to footer just to identify footer element. You can change later.

```css
.content {
  padding: 10.4%;
}

.main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.copyright {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  display: block; 
}

.navbarSocialMedia {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red; 
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFooter {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.navbarSocialMedia a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.mediaLogo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.try {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

  <title>Giving Back</title>

  <link href="simpleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="name.png">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="services">

  <div class="header">

    <a href="simple.html">
      <img src="name.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"> </a>

    <div class="navBar">
      <a href="ourstory.html" class="ourstory">Our Story</a>
      <a href="services.html" class="services">Giving Back</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">

      <p class="p3"> content

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="footer">
    <div class="navbarSocialMedia">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </a>
      <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com " target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a>
    </div>
    <p class=" copyright ">Copyright &copy;. </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```